# auto_now_add only if value if empty in django

Tags: django

I have datetimefield that I want to create an automatic record of the date only if I did not specify a value for it, because sometimes i put a specific date

The code :

```
record_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

I try with "editable = True" but it is the same result

How can I impose this condition?

Comment: you can take another field which is by default recording time at every create view and use this one also. If user has entered the value in this field then don't show the recorded field, but leave this as blank = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, you shouldn't use auto_now_add. Instead you should override save() like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.date_field is None:
            self.date_field = datetime.datetime.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Source: [Explicitly passing a date to a DateTimeField](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16583)